# How to solve "Manage your energy"?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I read an [optimisation problem about energy](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2418487/dashboard#s=p1) in Google Code Jam. (The contest is over now, so it's okay to talk about it)

> You've got a very busy calendar today, full of important stuff to do.
>   You worked hard to prepare and make sure all the activities don't
>   overlap. Now it's morning, and you're worried that despite all of your
>   enthusiasm, you won't have the energy to do all of this with full
>   engagement.
>
> You will have to manage your energy carefully. You start the day full
>   of energy - E joules of energy, to be precise. You know you can't go
>   below zero joules, or you will drop from exhaustion. You can spend any
>   non-negative, integer number of joules on each activity (you can spend
>   zero, if you feel lazy), and after each activity you will regain R
>   joules of energy. No matter how lazy you are, however, you cannot have
>   more than E joules of energy at any time; any extra energy you would
>   regain past that point is wasted.
>
> Now, some things (like solving Code Jam problems) are more important
>   than others. For the ith activity, you have a value vi that expresses
>   how important this activity is to you. The gain you get from each
>   activity is the value of the activity, multiplied by the amount of
>   energy you spent on the activity (in joules). You want to manage your
>   energy so that your total gain will be as large as possible.
>
> Note that you cannot reorder the activities in your calendar. You just
>   have to manage your energy as well as you can with the calendar you
>   have.
>
> Input
>
> The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test
>   cases follow. Each test case is described by two lines. The first
>   contains three integers: E, the maximum (and initial) amount of
>   energy, R, the amount you regain after each activity, and N, the
>   number of activities planned for the day. The second line contains N
>   integers vi, describing the values of the activities you have planned
>   for today.
>
> Output
>
> For each test case, output one line containing "Case #x: y", where x
>   is the case number (starting from 1) and y is the maximum gain you can
>   achieve by managing your energy that day.

How can this problem be solved? I was thinking if it could be solved by Dynamic Programming. Any leads?

Comment: Yes! You don't need to know dynamic programming to solve the problem, but it's a sensible line of attack. Reason that the best decision at any time doesn't depend on previous decisions except via the amount of energy they left you. That suggests defining `f(n,e)` as the optimal score after n activities leaving you with e points of energy. So `f(0,e) = 0`. You can write a recurrence relation expressing `f(n,·)` in terms of `f(n-1,·)` and `v_n`. The answer to the original problem will be `max_e f(N,e)`.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question and the recurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can simply be done by recursion, code attached below: here status is the array for v as in problem

```
    public static long calculate(long limit,long initialEnergy,long R,long[] status,int start){
    long leftEnergy = 0;
    long  maxGain = 0;
    if(start + 1 > status.length){
        return  0;
    }
    for(long taskEnergy = initialEnergy; taskEnergy>=0;taskEnergy--){
        leftEnergy = initialEnergy - taskEnergy + R;
        if(leftEnergy > limit){
            leftEnergy = limit;
        }
        long gain = status[start] * taskEnergy + calculate(limit,leftEnergy, R, status, start +1);
        if(gain > maxGain){
            maxGain = gain;
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(start + " " +  maxGain);
    return maxGain;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Very elegant. You solved this during the contest?

Answer (score -1):

Imagine the energy spent on each activity as a coordinate in a multi-dimensional space. Imagine the gain earned as the temperature of the point in that multi-dimensional space. (Treat impossible combinations as having zero gain.) This reduces the problem to "find the hottest point in a room". And that's easy -- start anywhere (probably, for simplicity, start with zero energy spent on each activity since at least that's guaranteed to be legal), keep moving in any direction that makes it hotter, and stop when no direction makes it hotter.

Intuitively, it seems to me like you can't get stuck in a local maximum (because the output is a linear, clamped function of the input). But if you're worried about it, when you stop, "kick yourself" in a random direction and try again. If you repeat this a few times and land consistently in the same spot, you can be reasonably confident that's the global maximum.

To use a gravity metaphor, essentially, you map the problem to a space. You map the best solution to the lowest point in the space. Then it's as easy as just falling to the bottom.